# kotlin sumar saldo anterior

Tags: kotlin, reduce

Tengo una tabla que agrupo items por fecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi intención es que en la columna saldo muestre el saldo real.

```
MARZO 180 * 
Abril saldo de marzo + importe de abril - pagado = 120 * 
MAYO saldo de abril + importe de mayo - pagado = 250
```

¿Como lo puedo conseguir? Con los `println` me funciona perfecto pero no se muestra en la tabla.
Aqui mi codigo

```
            importeAcumulados = (tiempoHorasAcumulados!! *10f).toInt()
            pagosAcumulados = res.pagado.toInt()
            saldo = importeAcumulados!!

            pagos.addAll(listOf( PagosText(
                fechaGroupAcumulados!!, tiempoHorasAcumulados!!, importeAcumulados!!, pagosAcumulados!!,
                saldo!!
            )))

            val totalSaldo = pagos.sumOf { it.saldo }
            //println("May saldo: $totalSaldo")
            tvTitle.text = "Tabla de horas y cobros:\nFaltan a cobrar: $totalSaldo €"
        }
    }

    val result = pagos
        .groupingBy { Triple(it.fecha, it.fecha, it.fecha) }
        .reduce { _, acc, element ->
            acc.copy(fecha = acc.fecha, tiempoAcumulado = acc.tiempoAcumulado + element.tiempoAcumulado, importe = acc.importe + element.importe,
                pagado = acc.pagado + element.pagado, saldo = acc.saldo + element.saldo)

        }
        .values.toList()

    recyclerViewMovieList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerViewMovieList.adapter = TableViewAdapter(result)
```

Comment: Código editado la lista que pasaba a result no la había puesto, y la que mostraba anteriormente  no era la que enviaba al adapter, pero así tampoco lo e conseguido

Comment: Hola Rafa, en la columna "Saldo" para obtener su valor, se debe realizar de esta forma: "MARZO 180 * 
Abril saldo de marzo + importe de abril - pagado = 120 * 
MAYO saldo de abril + importe de mayo - pagado = 250" ?

Comment: @Jorgesys es lo que pregunto, ¿Quieres decir?

Comment: Rafa, es que no entiendo muy bien, para obtener el "Saldo" actual es: saldo de del mes anterior + importe del mes actual - pagado actual ? @RafaCF tienes url de proyecto en github

Comment: @Jorgesy, No, no esta en github, el problema es que se como hacerlo

Comment: @RafaelCF en este println("May saldo: $totalSaldo") se imprime correctamente el valor que necesitas?

Comment: @Jorgesys No me lo imprime sin lo pagado, o sea sin la resta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar:

*Explicación en comentarios*

```
    val result = pagos
        .groupingBy { Triple(it.fecha, it.fecha, it.fecha) }
        .reduce { _, acc, element ->
            acc.copy(fecha = acc.fecha, tiempoAcumulado = acc.tiempoAcumulado + element.tiempoAcumulado, importe = acc.importe + element.importe,
                pagado = acc.pagado + element.pagado, saldo = acc.saldo + element.saldo)

        }
        .values.toList()
    
  
    var saldoAnterior = result[0].saldo; //rescatamos el primer saldo
    val result2=result.mapIndexed { index, pago ->
        if(index==0) //el primer pago lo saltamos, retornando el pago actual directamente
        {
            pago
        }
        else{ // para el pago 2 (indice=1) en adelante

            //calculamos el saldo del mes
             var saldoMes= saldoAnterior + pago.importe - pago.pagado
             saldoAnterior = saldoMes //lo guardamos como saldo anterior para la próxima iteración
             pago.copy(saldo = saldoMes) //retornamos el pago actualizado
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/386507)

Comment: @Yussef la primera y segunda fila correcto, la tercera linea ya mal, pongo captura si quieres

Comment: @RafelC.F he actualizado el código, favor prueba nuevamente

Comment: @Mateo Eso que estaba proporcionaba ciertamente una respuesta. De paso agradezco a mis fans que siempre están muy preocupados de votarme negativo, sin ustedes yo no soy nada.

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146496/discussion-on-answer-by-yussef-kotlin-sumar-saldo-anterior); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Comment: @Yussef me he surgido un error puedo seguir preguntando?

Comment: @RafelC.F Claro, es el propósito del sitio :P. Si tiene que ver con el código de mi respuesta puedes realizarla aquí en los comentarios, si no es mi código deberías realizar una nueva pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @Yussef si es tu código, lo que intento es restar minutos al tiempoAcumulado pero solo restar 510 minutos al dia. Puedo formular la pregunta respondiendo a mi pregunta para poner el codigo de lo que estoy haciendo?

Comment: @RafelC.F no, la seccion respuestas son solo para respuestas. Lo que planteas es un cambio de escenario de la pregunta original, por lo que debes crear un pregunta nueva

Comment: @Yussef perfecto voy a poner una nueva pregunta